# Unable to get data using child.before in pexpect

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting, pexpect

```
    ip="99.78.992.02"
    prompt="\$"
    log_file_handle = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "log_file"),"a")
    child = pexpect.spawn("ssh abc@%s" % ip, logfile=log_file_handle) # this works because I have public-private key set up
    child.sendline("ls -l")
    child.expect(prompt)
    print "child.before %s" % child.before
    print "child.after %s" % child.after
```

The response I am getting is:

```
    child.before  
    Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-67-generic-pae i686)

     * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

    360 packages can be updated.
    305 updates are security updates.

    New release '14.04.1 LTS' available.
    Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.



    *** /dev/sda4 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***
    *** /dev/sda2 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***

    No mail.
    Last login: Wed Mar  4 13:44:40 2015 from 10.49.92.49
    ls
    abc@mycomputer:~
    child.after $
```

Why am I not getting the output from "ls -l" in child.before? Can someone comment on this please?

Comment: I haven't used pexpect for a while, but remember that some shells seemed to have difficulty spotting the prompt

Comment: have you tried to wait for prompt *before* and *after*  `ls`?1. in order to enter `ls -l` normally, you would wait for the prompt after `ssh`ing 2. to get the `ls` result you would wait for the next prompt -- two prompts total.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Waiting for the prompts fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As J.F. Sebastian said in the comments, I had to wait for the prompt before issuing a command.